# When to use Train Validation Test sets

Tags: r, validation, testing, split

I know this question is quite common but I have looked at all the questions that have been asked before and I still can't understand why we also need a validation set.
I know sometimes people only use a train set and a test set, so why do we also need a validation set?
And how do we use it?
For example, in order to impute missing data, I impute these 3 different sets separately or not?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer with an example.

If I'm training a neural network or doing linear regression, and I'm using only train and test data I can check my test data loss for each iteration and stop when my test data loss begins to grow or get a snapshot of the model with the lowest test loss.

Is some sense this is "overfiting" to my test data since i decide when to stop based on that.

If I was using test, train and validation data I can do the same process as above with the validation instead of the test data, and then after i decide when my model is done training, I can test it on the never before seen test data to give me a more unbiased score of my models predictions.

For the second part of the question, I would suggest to treat at least the test data as independent and impute the missing data differently, but it depends on the situation and data.