# How can adjust train-set and test-set and validation-set for Keras in RNN?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, cross-validation, recurrent-neural-network

I'm playing with the dataset which are time-series and by help of reshape I fetch them to RNN.

The dataset contains 40 time-steps [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YgbhwIgnW42bwOnaxM2e_JHwsf3Q9O2_/view?usp=sharing) I hope each time 1 row which contains 1440 columns fetch to RNN and get trained andin the end 40 times (1, 1440) feed and learn in RNN.

```
X_train size: (40, 1, 1440)
X_test size: (40, 1, 1440)
```

**Problem** is I want to split dataset into : 
**data-set** , **validation-set** and **test-set** so that I can predict after **timestep=t** and plot the output.

[image: img] I already read @YSelf [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48811058/10452700) and [the reason why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55847067/10452700) it's helpful but unfortunately I haven't set up successfully yet due to structure of data. 
is I want to provide the condition that I can adjust in implementation scripts so that let's say I'm interested in predicting timesteps after 35th row or time-step till end. How I can fulfill it and how I can demonstrate its plot?

my code is following:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.layers import Dense , Activation , BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import LSTM,SimpleRNN
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop

data_train = pd.read_csv("D:\Train.csv", header=None)

#select interested columns to predict 980 out of 1440 for prediction
j=0
index=[]
for i in range(1439):
    if j==2:
        j=0
        continue
    else:
        index.append(i)
        j+=1

Y_train = data_train[index]
Y_test  = data_test[index]
data_train = data_train.values
data_test  = data_test.values
X_train = data_train .reshape((data_train.shape[0], 1,data_train.shape[1]))
X_test  = data_test  .reshape((data_test.shape[0] , 1 ,data_test.shape[1]))


# create and fit the SimpleRNN model
model_RNN = Sequential()
model_RNN.add(SimpleRNN(units=1440, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))) #in real data units=1440
model_RNN.add(Dense(960)) # in real data Dense(960)
model_RNN.add(BatchNormalization())
model_RNN.add(Activation('tanh'))
model_RNN.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
hist_RNN=model_RNN.fit(X_train[:30, :], Y_train[30:, :], epochs =50, batch_size =20,validation_data=(X_train[:30, :], Y_train[30:, :]),verbose=1)
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could explain answer of questions. Thanks in advance.